# More than one example_frequency.yaml in Elastalert

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elastalert

I am working on elastalert. I am able to send the email alerts whenever my condition matches.
Now my use case is I want to send email whenever any error is encountered.

So if its error : email content body should be "ERROR OCCURED"
else
if it's FATAL : email content body should be "FATAL ERROR"

I have following example_frequency.yaml :

```
name: Error Occurred in your Application
type: frequency
index: logstash-*
num_events: 1
timframe: 
hours:1
filter:
 -query: 
   query_string:
        query: "message: *ERROR* OR message: *FATAL*"
alert:
- "email"

alert_text_type: "alert_text_only"
alert_text: |
    Error occured at {0}
    Host Machine id: {1}
    Error Message: {2}
    Log File Location: {3}
alert_text_args:
    - "@timestamp"
    - "beat.hostname"
    - "message"
    - "source"
email:
- "test@gmail.com"
```

With this configuration even its FATAL/ERROR I am getting the same email content. I want to change some text if its FATAL.
Is there any wa to do it in ElastAlert?
Please help guys!

Comment: Tech Geek did you find a solution  for this? it's an interesting question, I voted up.

Comment: Hi yes. You need to create multiple rules for it and it'll work. When elastalert starts it'll load all rules which are available under elastalert/example_rules folder, so make multiple rules and patterns accordingly.